# Finding child from parent of clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, getelementbyid

I'm currently building an event table that will feature a "share" button. Once the user clicks on the share button I want to find text value from that particular table and store them in a variable so that I can use them in my next step. Basicly when I click the share button I want to find the parent element that wraps the particular table and then find text values from each particular cell and store that in a variable. In my JSFiddle I have setup to display the results in the resultbox. http://jsfiddle.net/Ak84L/5/

```
$("#shareButt").click(function(){ 

 var date = $(this).parent('.even_table').find('date').text();

 $(".resultbox").text("date"+date);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change `shareButt` and `date` to values of `class` attribute instead of `id`, because IDs have to be unique.

And use this code:

```
$(".shareButt").click(function () {
    var date = $(this).closest('.event_table').find('.date').text();
    $(".resultbox").text("date" + date);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/Ak84L/8/)

Comment: And fix the `even_table` typo to be `event_table`.

Comment: @Scimonster yeah!, was wondering why it didn't work and removed the demo.. Now its back.. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

First **DON'T** use same id. Use `class` instead. Go this way:

**js**

```
$(".shareButt").click(function(){    
     var date = $(this).parents(".event_table").find(".date").text();    
     $(".resultbox").text("date"+date);

});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ak84L/11/)

Answer (score 2):

it would be much simpler to append a custom data tag to the element than to muck around with artsy fartsy jquery calls.

If its good enough for major web frameworks like `angular.js`, `jade`, `bootstrap`, etc. why do many people continue to attempt to reinvent the wheel to create the most complicated solution.

[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r3wt/Ak84L/15/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="shareButt" date-data="12.5.2014">SHARE</div></td>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".shareButt").click(function(){    
     $('.resultbox').text('date' + $(this).attr('date-data'));
});
```